# Jupiterlab print DataFrame nicely

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

If you let the a Dataframe at the end of a cell you get a nice table that react to the mouse (mouse-over makes the line blue). Considering that I want to print a set of DataFrames like that, how may I do it?

Comment: What does it mean to "let a Dataframe at the end of a cell"?

Comment: ATL found the intention. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display` function

```py
from IPython.display import display
```

and in your targeted cell

```py
display(df1)
#
# Some code here
#
display(df2)
```